# Install the Kohana Framework on a PHP - Web Hosting Server

Tags: php, kohana, web-hosting

Could the PHP Kohana Framework be installed on any Web Hosting Server which provides PHP5?

I wonder because it is purely written in PHP5 built-in objects.

Do I have to be aware of any extraordinary setups or can I simply follow the installation documentation and get it run on the web hosting server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you upload the files to your server and try to access the index.php, the system will automatically call the install.php and check whether Kohana will run on the server or not.

You can see the requirements in the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/install)

[image]

**Update**

I just had the problem that I tried installing Kohana on a server with only basic PHP extension installed. The Environment Test didn't fail, however I got a white page when trying to access it (after removing install.php).

The problem was `mbstring` wasn't yet installed and Kohana didn't check for it, just assumed it was.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kohana can be installed on just about any server. There are some optional things, like image manipulation and emailing, that will not work if the extensions are not installed/enabled, though.

You can go through Kohana's documentation and figure this out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

How to install Kohana (on a shared host or elsewhere) :

1. Download Kohana
2. Put the content of the folder `kohana-vx.x.x` on any part of your server that can be accessed from a browser.
3. Browser to that folder
4. Follow the instructions in `install.php`.
5. When at least all of the mandatory options are in green, remove `install.php`.
6. If you then see an error message instead of `hello, world!`, open the file `application/bootstrap.php` with your text editor and replace the value of `base_url` with `str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], '', getcwd()) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` or whatever `string` this code gives you.

That's all it takes to install Kohana on ANY system.